# What happens to settlements if I leave them empty or unoccupied?

Tags: fallout-4

I am choosing to leave Red Rocket Gas Station completely empty for a number of reasons.

Will anything happen to it?

Will it get taken over by Raiders or wild animals or will it just remain empty until I start building things in there?

If a settlement has things like beds or food but no people, is it "safe" to leave alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing - if you have an empty settlement and it gets attacked, you might lose some of the custom structures located at the settlement but there are no people to kill and the happiness level of the settlement doesn't seem to drop below 50%. Additionally settlements do not appear to ever get "taken over".

Comment: To add to this, I left the Red Rocket settlement unoccupied for at least 50 hours of playtime, until I eventually turned it into the place I send my companions when they're not with me. It seems like a few hostiles wandered up from Concord because one of my turrets was lightly damaged when I returned to actually use it, but yeah, "nothing" is what happens to unoccupied settlements. I've also left Jamaica Plains empty (and completely unimproved) for about 80 hours of playtime, and nothing's happened to it, not even a "help defend" event, so maybe those only happen to settlements with settlers.